# How to make a window detectable by a Capture Software

Tags: java, libgdx, video-capture

I have made a game in java with the library Libgdx.

I would like to capture a video of my game in window mode, I got Overwolf software for video capture, but my game is not detected by the software. Otherwise All my games installed in the computer are detected in window mode (CounterStrike, League of legend, Battlefield, etc..)

My game use openGl to render textures.

I need a solution for this, it can be a solution inside the code of the game, or outside.

Comment: Does Overwolf capture games in windowed mode? Maybe it'll recognize the game if it's in fullscreen. Also, maybe Overwolf has a set list of games that it recognizes as games?

Comment: yes Overwolf capture games in windowed mode, it works with Counter Strike for exemple

Answer (score 0):

you can easily implement your own "game recorder" using [LibGDX Screen Factory](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Take-a-Screenshot) and then just use an external tool to generate .avi file from screenshots set (or use example they's gave on the page)

If for some reason you want to use external tool you should focus on your Desktop LwjglApplicationConfiguration object and play with [its fields](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplicationConfiguration.java)

Comment: I would like to use an external tool, It works when I use Fraps, but doesn't when I use Overwolf, I'm wondering what is the point.